# Speeding up string splitting and concatenation

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler's problem #35](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=35)

> The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.
>
> How many circular primes are there below one million?

**This is my solution:**

```
import numpy as np

def problem(n=100):

    circulars = np.array([], np.int32)

    p = np.array(sieveOfAtkin(n), np.int32)
    for prime in p:
        prime_str = str(prime)
        is_circular = True
        for i in xrange(len(prime_str)):
            m = int(prime_str[i:]+prime_str[:i])
            if not m in p:
                is_circular = False

        if is_circular:
            circulars = np.append(circulars, [prime])

    return len(circulars)
```

**Unfortunately the for-loop is mighty slow! Any ideas how I can speed this up?
I suspect the string concatenation is the bottleneck, but I am not entirely sure! :)**

---

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Why are you using a string at all?

Comment: Don't use a NumPy array for `circulars` -- it has fixed size and needs to be reallocated on *every* call to `numpy.append()`.  A Python list is the better choice here.  (Removing the numpy tag since neither the question nor the current answer are related to numpy.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use a set for membership testing instead of an array. The hash lookup will be O(1) instead of O(n). This is the biggest bottleneck.
2. Break out of the loop as soon as you see that it's not a circular prime instead of trying the other rotations. This is another bottleneck.

---

Here, I've isolated the circularity testing into a function to allow the list to be built with a list comprehension. Having it in a function, lets it return `False` as soon as we know it's not circular. Another alternative would be to do it in a `for` loop and `break` when we know it's not circular. Then append to the list in the loop's `else` clause. Generally speaking, list comps are faster than appending in a loop though. That might not be the case here because it does add function call overhead. If you really care about speed, it would be worth it to profile both options.

```
primes = set(primes_to_one_million_however_you_want_to_get_them)

def is_circular(prime, primes=primes):
   prime_str = str(prime)
   # With thanks to Sven Marnach's comments
   return all(int(prime_str[i:]+prime_str[:i]) in primes 
              for i in xrange(len(prime_str)))


circular_primes = [p for p in primes if is_circular(p)]
```

I've also used the trick of passing a global as a default argument to the `is_circular` function. This means that it can be accessed within the function as a local variable instead of a global variable which is faster.

Here's one way to code it using an `else` clause on a loop to get rid of that ugly flag and improve efficiency.

```
circular = []
for p in primes:
   prime_str = str(prime)
   for i in xrange(len(prime_str)):
       if int(prime_str[i:]+prime_str[:i]) not in primes:
            break
   else:
       circular.append(p)
```

Comment: @RadiantHex. Read about hash tables. The answer is that sets are implemented using a hash table. This allows O(1) membership testing. For a list or array, membership testing involves looping over __every__ element until a match is found. In the worst case where no match is found, every element has to be looked at so it's O(n).

Comment: @aaron: awesome! Thank you so much! I definitely learnt some useful things today :)

Comment: The last four lines of `is_circular()` can be rewritten as `return all(int(prime_str[i:]+prime_str[:i]) in primes for i in xrange(len(prime_str)))`.  This should be even faster.

Comment: @Sven Good catch. See my edit. Doing it that way, lets you get rid of the function call overhead all together.

Comment: Oh, and yet another remark -- The `xrange` may start at 1, since we already know `p` is prime.

Comment: Getting rid of the function call might even slow things down because now we have to access global variables all the time.

Comment: @Sven, `prime_str` not being defined kills it. Don't know how I missed that. As far as the globals goes, I was expecting it to be in a function so they'd be locals. I'll just rewrite the first version and go to bed ;) Thanks for the input.